# Eval not declaring functions

Tags: javascript, function, eval

I have a code string I'm given that's already created for me elsewhere, using Blockly. It looks to me like it's correct, when I echo it straight out to a page:

```
function someName(){
    //some code
}
//more code
someName();
```

However, when I call eval on it, the function call itself does not work. It claims the function is not defined. Everything but the function declarations is working. The code string itself is set, and I can't change it unless I do a lot of parsing. Is there some simpler way to get these functions declared so the code can call them?

Test case (that I actually used):

```
function test(){
    alert("This is a test");
}
test();
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple test case? I can't easily recreate your issue. (i.e., `eval("function someName(){console.log(1)}; someName();")` correctly logs `1` as I expect)

Comment: Your "test case" is just your original code with a different name. I think @apsillers was looking for, you know, something actually demonstrating the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval` works within a very special environment which is in many ways a lot like **local** scope. So if you're calling `eval` on that string within a function, the `someName` function will only be declared *within that function*, e.g.:

```js
function doSomething(str) {
  eval(str);
  snippet.log(typeof someName); // "function"
}
doSomething("function someName() { }");
snippet.log(typeof someName); // "undefined"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

If you want it declared globally, you have to do some work. Kangax [wrote up an excellent discussion of the options](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/) for "global `eval`". One of the options is the one David Flanagan suggested:

```
var geval = this.execScript || eval;
```

Then use `geval`. This works because IE has `execScript`, which works at global scope, and in other browsers calling `eval` *indirectly* through a variable referring to it makes it work at global scope as well. But read the article for more details and options.

```js
function doSomething(str) {
  var geval = this.execScript || eval;
  geval(str);
  snippet.log(typeof someName); // "function"
}
doSomething("function someName() { }");
snippet.log(typeof someName); // "function"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: But op seems to have the function call within the very same code string?

Comment: @Bergi: Yes indeed, but it's not at all clear to me what they mean by "doesn't work." I'm assuming, since `eval` *does* work, that they're expecting the function to be declared in code outside the string after they eval it, and probably outside the function in which they eval'd it as well. I could, of course, be wrong. :-)

Comment: Ah, yes, it seems to be working now! Thank you so much. I figured it was something to do with how eval worked, but I couldn't find enough information through searching to realize the distinction.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Ah, a successful case of a [speculative answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288376/1048572) :-)

Comment: @Bergi: *Somewhat* speculative. After all, we know `eval` works, so it was a fairly educated guess. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`eval` only works for it's local scope as mentioned above, however , you can declare another version of eval function , and add it to the window object so the evaluated code functions will be accessable from the global context :

```
// add global 
window.$eval = eval;
// now use $_eval version wherever you want 
function someFunction(){
   // use the $eval function 
   window.$eval('function doSomething() { }');
}

someFunction();
typeof doSomething == 'function' // true
```